# Is there a way to have a SetUpFixture that runs once per class instead of once per namespace?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-mvc-5

**Scenario**
First of all, I'm new to testing - so please bear with me. Inside of my *test project*, there is a Controllers folder. The Controllers folder may contain a ControllerATest.cs, ControllerBTest.cs, and ControllerCTest.cs. Because my namespace aligns with my folder structure, they all share the namespace MyProject.Tests.Controllers.

From what I've read in the [NUnit SetUpFixture Documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4), a [SetUpFixture] inside this namespace will run once *for the entire namespace*. That is, if I run all of my controller tests at once - the SetUpFixture will be executed only once.

**Problem**
As I said, each controller test shares a namespace. SetUpFixtures apply to the entire namespace. What if I want each controller to have their *own* SetUpFixture? This is a problem when SetUpFixtures apply to entire namespaces. What I want is something that executes once, and not per-test. One of the things I do inside my SetUpFixture's SetUp is instantiate a controller. Sure, I could instantiate all 3 controllers in the SetUpFixture, but this seems ugly when maybe I am only testing ControllerC. That really doesn't seem clean. Therefore, I would like a SetUpFixture that applies *only* to the class it appears in, such as ControllerCTests.

From what I've read, this specific functionality seems to be impossible with NUnit. And if it's not possible with NUnit, that makes me think it's not a common scenario. And if it's not a common scenario, I am doing something wrong. My question is, what? Maybe my testing structure is off and it needs to change. Or maybe it *is* possible with NUnit?

**Code**
An example of my desired structure:

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.Controllers
{
public class ControllerATests
{
    private static IMyProjectRepository _fakeRepository;
    private static ControllerA _controllerA;

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class before_tests_run
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void ControllerASetup()
        {
            _fakeRepository = FakeRepository.Create();

            _controllerA = new ControllerA(_fakeRepository);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class when_ControllerA_index_get_action_executes
    {
        [Test]
        public void it_does_something()
        {
            //
        }

        [Test]
        public void it_does_something_else()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}

public class ControllerBTests
{
    private static IMyProjectRepository _fakeRepository;
    private static ControllerB _controllerB;

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class before_tests_run
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void ControllerBSetup()
        {
            _fakeRepository = FakeRepository.Create();

            _controllerB = new ControllerB(_fakeRepository);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class when_ControllerB_index_get_action_executes
    {
        [Test]
        public void it_does_something()
        {
            //
        }

        [Test]
        public void it_does_something_else()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Things I've Tried**

- Moving each .cs file into its own folder, so they have different namespaces. Technically this solves the problem, it just seems a little ugly to have a bunch of subfolders with only 1 item in each of them. Ugly, and will no longer match my parent project's structure which I was going for. But - maybe this is the way to go.
- Not instantiating my controller in the *SetUpFixture* SetUp, and instead doing it in the *TestFixture* SetUp so that a new one gets instantiated for every test (ex: 5 tests = 5 separate instances) instead of once per class or namespace. Though it seems like if I can get away with only creating 1 instance, I should.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a [`TestFixtureSetUpAttribute`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.6.4) on a method in your Controller class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class when_ControllerA_index_get_action_executes
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetUp()
    {
        // this code runs once no matter how many tests are in this class
    }

    [Test]
    public void it_does_something()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

From the documentation:

> This attribute is used inside a TestFixture to provide a single set of functions that are performed once prior to executing any of the tests in the fixture.

Here, "TestFixture" is synonymous with `class`.

Comment: Thank you - I had read the documentation for that, but misunderstood it thinking it was essentially the same thing as the SetUpFixture. This is a huge improvement, as it is ran only once per TestFixture, but it's still tied to an individual TestFixture; ideally it'd be tied to the class level (`public class ControllerATests`). For example, each class I have for each controller contains _several_ TestFixture classes. Therefore, I wish I could have this at the overall class level instead of individual TestFixture, but again, still an improvement.

Comment: Look at Tyler's answer below if you are using Nunit 3.0 or greater.

Answer (score 57):

For NUnit **3.4.1** and later, use [OneTimeSetUp](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute):

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // one time setup code for this class
    }
}
```

By the way, [TestFixtureSetUp](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureSetUp-Attribute) has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, and intuitively, the equivalent "per TestFixture" teardown attribute is `[OneTimeTearDown]`.