# How to have a setup function only run once per test session in NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-2.5

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace NUnitTest
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class GlobalSetup
    {
        static int test = 0;

        [SetUp]
        public void ImportConfigurationData ()
        {
            test++;
            Console.WriteLine (test);
        }
    }
}
```

If I repeatedly run my tests along with this global setup function (using the standard [NUnit GUI runner](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.5)), the number that is printed increases by one each time. In other words, this function is run multiple times per test session.

Is there another way to really have a function run once per test session, or is this a bug in the runner?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cheap workaround.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace NUnitTest
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class GlobalSetup
    {
        // The setup fixture seems to be bugged somewhat.
        // Therefore we manually check if we've run before.
        static bool WeHaveRunAlready = false;

        [SetUp]
        public void ImportConfigurationData ()
        {
            if (WeHaveRunAlready)
                return;

            WeHaveRunAlready = true;

            // Do my setup stuff here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For NUnit 3.4.1 and later, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38310496/1497596).